# How can i use the first 20 keys in dictionary to print the rest of the keys in the dictionary in this case to 40

Tags: python, dictionary

```
menue = {1:('Baklava', 45.50), 2:('Dolma', 43.50), 3:('Falafel', 35.50), 4:('Fattoush', 51.80),
     5:('Foul meddamas', 50.40), 6:('Grilled hhalloumi', 40.50), 7:('Hummus', 30.20),
     8:('Iraqi masgouf', 50.80), 9:('Kebab karaz', 50.60), 10:('Knsfeh', 32.95), 11:('Kofta', 37.50),
     12:('Manakeesh', 35.60), 13:('Mansaf', 32.20), 14:('Moutabal', 37.30), 15:('Quwarmah Al Dajaj', 45.40),
     16:('Shanklish', 37.40), 17:('Shawarma', 35.20), 18:('Shish tawook', 39.50), 19:('Taboulrh', 45.80),
     20:('Um Ali', 35.90), 41:('Airan', 8.50), 42:('Coca-Cola', 5.00), 43:('Coffee Americano', 6.50),
     44:('Coffee Black Tea', 6.50), 45:('Coffee Cappuccino', 6.00), 46:('Coffee Caramel', 3.00),
     47:('Coffee Espresso', 6.50), 48:('Coffee Lattr', 5.50), 49:('Coffee Macchiato', 5.00),
     50:('Coffee Mochachino', 6.50), 51:('Fanta', 5.00), 52:('Milk', 9.00), 53:('Sprite', 5.00),
     54:('Tea Ahmad', 5.50), 55:('Tea Black', 4.00), 56:('Tea Lemon', 4.50), 57:('Tea Lipton', 5.00),
     58:('Tea Milk', 6.00), 59:('Tea Simba', 8.50), 60:('Water', 3.00)}

print(f"""
       ORDER FOODS & DRINKS
        |NO|  |FOOD NAME|      |PRICE|        |NO|  |DRINK NAME|  |PRICE|
        (1)     {menue[1][0]}         {menue[1][1]}         (41)    {menue[41][0]}         {menue[41][1]}
        (2)      {menue[2][0]}          {menue[2][1]}         (42)    {menue[42][0]}     {menue[42][1]}
        (3)     {menue[3][0]}         {menue[3][1]}         (43) {menue[43][0]} {menue[43][1]}
        (4)    {menue[4][0]}         {menue[4][1]}         (44) {menue[44][0]} {menue[44][1]}
        (5)   {menue[5][0]}     {menue[5][1]}         (45) {menue[45][0]} {menue[45][1]}
        (6) {menue[6][0]}   {menue[6][1]}         (46) {menue[46][0]}   {menue[46][1]}
        (7)     {menue[7][0]}          {menue[7][1]}         (47) {menue[47][0]}  {menue[47][1]}
        (8)  {menue[8][0]}      {menue[8][1]}         (48)   {menue[48][0]}   {menue[48][1]}
        (9)   {menue[9][0]}       {menue[9][1]}         (49)   {menue[49][0]} {menue[49][1]}
        (10)   {menue[10][0]}            {menue[10][1]}       (50)   {menue[50][0]} {menue[50][1]}
        (11)   {menue[11][0]}             {menue[11][1]}        (51)   {menue[51][0]}        {menue[51][1]}
        (12)   {menue[12][0]}         {menue[12][1]}        (52)   {menue[52][0]}         {menue[52][1]}
        (13)   {menue[13][0]}            {menue[13][1]}        (53)   {menue[53][0]}       {menue[53][1]}
        (14)   {menue[14][0]}          {menue[14][1]}        (54)   {menue[54][0]}    {menue[54][1]}
        (15) {menue[15][0]}   {menue[15][1]}        (55)   {menue[55][0]}    {menue[55][1]}
        (16)  {menue[16][0]}          {menue[16][1]}        (56)   {menue[56][0]}    {menue[56][1]}
        (17)   {menue[17][0]}          {menue[17][1]}        (57)   {menue[57][0]}   {menue[57][1]}
        (18) {menue[18][0]}        {menue[18][1]}        (58)   {menue[58][0]}     {menue[58][1]}
        (19)   {menue[19][0]}          {menue[19][1]}        (59)   {menue[59][0]}    {menue[59][1]}
        (20)     {menue[20][0]}          {menue[20][1]}        (60)   {menue[60][0]}        {menue[60][1]}
```

Im new to pyton and still lerning.
This is the first thing i'v tried so it's look like in the picture
but they told me to use a for loop with only the first 20 key's as a range and print the other 20 with the loop
I try to len the dictionary and use only the first 20 indexes but then i have a problem to use them as keys.

This is how it's supposed to look the print menu

[image]

Comment: Hi. Your question is not clear to me. What does "the first 20 indexes of the dictionary" mean? The items in the dictionary can be stored in any order, so "first 20" by itself doesn't make sense. Do you mean you just want 20 and you don't care which? Or do you want the 20 with the lowest numeric values? I also have no idea what you mean by "use the first 20 keys to print the rest of the keys  in the dictionary in this case 40". How do you use one key to print another key? Can you give an example? Also, you mention "in this case 40", but in your data you show keys up to 60?

Comment: i was truing to use somthing like this  butt it didunt work i try to change the keys to str 
z = len(menue)
for k in range(20, z + 1, 40):
    if k >= 20:
        for k in menue.values():
            print(k)
tried this too but it is a loop of all the list cuz i didn't have a clue how exactly to do it

Comment: the first 20 are food the rest are drinks so the idea is to print the foods and with them the drinks
thhe keys are from 1 to 20 and from 41 to 60 wen i len them they are 40 that why im saying in this case 40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

```
food = [[i+1, menue[i + 1][0], "RM " + str(menue[i + 1][1])] for i in range(20)]
drinks = [[i, menue[i][0], "RM " + str(menue[i][1])] for i in range(41, 61)]

res = [x + y for x, y in zip(food, drinks)]
columns = ['NO', 'Food Name', 'Price', 'NO', 'Drink Name', 'Price']
print('*' * 28 + 'Order Foods & Drinks' + '*' * 28)
print(tabulate(res, headers=columns, tablefmt='grid'))
print('(M) Main Menu' + ' ' * 22 + '(P) Payment' + ' ' * 22 +  '(E) Exit')
```

**Output:**

```
****************************Order Foods & Drinks****************************
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   NO | Food Name         | Price    |   NO | Drink Name        | Price   |
+======+===================+==========+======+===================+=========+
|    1 | Baklava           | RM 45.5  |   41 | Airan             | RM 8.5  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|    2 | Dolma             | RM 43.5  |   42 | Coca-Cola         | RM 5.0  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|    3 | Falafel           | RM 35.5  |   43 | Coffee Americano  | RM 6.5  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|    4 | Fattoush          | RM 51.8  |   44 | Coffee Black Tea  | RM 6.5  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|    5 | Foul meddamas     | RM 50.4  |   45 | Coffee Cappuccino | RM 6.0  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|    6 | Grilled hhalloumi | RM 40.5  |   46 | Coffee Caramel    | RM 3.0  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|    7 | Hummus            | RM 30.2  |   47 | Coffee Espresso   | RM 6.5  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|    8 | Iraqi masgouf     | RM 50.8  |   48 | Coffee Lattr      | RM 5.5  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|    9 | Kebab karaz       | RM 50.6  |   49 | Coffee Macchiato  | RM 5.0  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   10 | Knsfeh            | RM 32.95 |   50 | Coffee Mochachino | RM 6.5  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   11 | Kofta             | RM 37.5  |   51 | Fanta             | RM 5.0  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   12 | Manakeesh         | RM 35.6  |   52 | Milk              | RM 9.0  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   13 | Mansaf            | RM 32.2  |   53 | Sprite            | RM 5.0  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   14 | Moutabal          | RM 37.3  |   54 | Tea Ahmad         | RM 5.5  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   15 | Quwarmah Al Dajaj | RM 45.4  |   55 | Tea Black         | RM 4.0  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   16 | Shanklish         | RM 37.4  |   56 | Tea Lemon         | RM 4.5  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   17 | Shawarma          | RM 35.2  |   57 | Tea Lipton        | RM 5.0  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   18 | Shish tawook      | RM 39.5  |   58 | Tea Milk          | RM 6.0  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   19 | Taboulrh          | RM 45.8  |   59 | Tea Simba         | RM 8.5  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
|   20 | Um Ali            | RM 35.9  |   60 | Water             | RM 3.0  |
+------+-------------------+----------+------+-------------------+---------+
(M) Main Menu                      (P) Payment                      (E) Exit
```